# boolean logic, true if 1 out of 4 are true

Tags: javascript, boolean

I have 4 variables, any of them can be true or false

```
var a
var b
var c
var d
```

I would like to test 3 conditions:

1. true if 1 out of 4 is true
2. true if 2 out of 4 is true
3. true if 3 out of 4 is true

I know that 0 out of 4 is true when:

```
a!=true && b!=true && c!=true && d!=true
```

and
4 out of 4 are true when:

```
a==true && b==true && c==true && d==true
```

but i cant think further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just add the variables with boolean values. The result is a number.

```
value = a + b + c + d;
```

Then you could make a check agains the number, you want to test.

```js
var a = false, b = true, c = true, d = true,
    value = a + b + c + d;

console.log(value);
```

Comment: Thanks, so simple, and worked like charm. Already tested, that was exactly what i needed.

Answer (score 1):

When dealing with a bunch of "things" that you want to run the same test on, it usually makes sense to group them using an array.

```
var collection = [a, b, c, d];
```

You can then get an array of elements that match a test with [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```
var true_elements = collection.filter(function (value) { return (value == true); });
```

You can then count the results:

```
console.log(true_elements.length);
```

And do whatever tests you like

```
if (true_elements.length === 1) { ... }
if (true_elements.length >= 1) { ... }
// etc
```

Comment: That's posh. I'm not sure I like the C-idiomatic way of adding the values when it comes to Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript allows you to add boolean types together. In doing this it converts the arguments to integral types with 1 for `true`, and 0 for `false`.

So you can write

`a + b + c + d == 3`

as your test for 3 `true` values and 1 `false` value.

Not all languages support this (e.g. Java), but Javascript, C, and C++ do. Take care with the Visual Basic type languages which use -1 as the `True` value.